# Store literal wildcard character in bash string

Tags: bash, variables, escaping, quoting, metacharacters

Say I have a function

```
print_args () {
    for i in $@; do
        echo "$i"
    done
}
```

When I do

```
foo='\*'
print_args $foo
```

I get

```
\*
```

(with the backslash) as output.

If I change the definition of `foo` to `foo='*'` instead, I get all the files in the current directory when running `print_args $foo`.

So I either get the backslash included, or the `*` interpreted, but I don't see how to get the `*` literally.

The output is the same whether I include double quotes around `$foo` or not.

Comment: Quote the expansion of `$foo`. `print_args "$foo"`

Comment: @Etan Sorry, I edited just before you finished your comment. It behaves the same double quotes or not.

Comment: Oh, you also need quotes around the expansion of `$@`. `for i in "$@"`. General rule: "Always quote your variable expansions."

Comment: Ah, that's it. I thought `$@` was special in that regard but I guess I was misremembering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule is to quote all variables. It prevents shell expansion and splitting on spaces. So your function should look like this (quoting `$@`, as well as `${array[@]}` splits by arguments):

```
print_args () {
    for i in "$@"; do
        echo "$i"
    done
}
```

And call it like this:

```
print_args "$foo"
```